# JavaFX Displaying Time and Refresh in Every Second

Tags: java, time, javafx, timer

Hello I would like to ask for any advice on this problem.

I would like to display current time in HH:MM:SS format (refreshing every second) in label or whatever component that is good for it.

Any advice?

EDIT: Someone asked for a code.. so I put it here for better description of the problem. "I have no code for that time What I'm trying to achieve is simple GUI diary and in one of the labels I would like to display time remaining until the closest event and in the other label I want to display like clocks that refreshes every second. I need it to get remaining time working. All I can think of is creating new thread that will do it and refreshes the clock, but I am not that advanced to use multithreading in JavaFX . So I was wondering if anyone can advice me with something less complicated than multithreading (I dont know how to implement that thread into JavaFX components)"

Answer (score 14):

Version with Timeline:

```
long endTime = ...;
Label timeLabel = new Label();
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "HH:mm:ss" );
final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(
        Duration.millis( 500 ),
        event -> {
            final long diff = endTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
            if ( diff < 0 ) {
            //  timeLabel.setText( "00:00:00" );
                timeLabel.setText( timeFormat.format( 0 ) );
            } else {
                timeLabel.setText( timeFormat.format( diff ) );
            }
        }
    )
);
timeline.setCycleCount( Animation.INDEFINITE );
timeline.play();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   Label main_clock_lb = new Label();
    Thread timerThread = new Thread(() -> {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); //1 second
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            final String time = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                main_clock_lb.setText(time);
            });
        }
    });   timerThread.start();//start the thread and its ok
```

Comment: #1 added one label to display the time , so u know that #2 I declare a thread which will keep running even after gui view , #3 it will then define an date  format, #3 it will continuously run while i is true (this may be modified) then while running infinite (depend on how much u will keep app running) and thread will always update  the time but to ensure that time will change on every second we put that thread to sleep for (1000 milliseconds -> 1 second) after that it will initialize the date string and update it again and again to the label of clock ( main_clock_lb.setText(time); )

Comment: Platform.runLater(() -> {
                main_clock_lb.setText(time); 
            }); //Run the specified Runnable on the JavaFX Application Thread at some unspecified time in the future. so at the moment where i want time to be edited

Comment: please edit your answer and add the explanation (vs doing so in comments) - also note, that there is no reason to go so low-level (as creating/sleeping a background thread, then wrap the actual update into a runlater) in javafx, it has reasonable concurrency support built-in (see the answers using Timeline, f.i.)

Comment: don't use this implementation. It makes the application performance poor.

Answer (score 1):

One might find helpful how to print date and time for javaFx.

```
final Label clock = new Label();
final DateFormat format = DateFormat.getInstance();
final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), 
new EventHandler() 
{
@Override  
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) 
    {
      final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      clock.setText(format.format(cal.getTime());
    }
});

timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.DateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score -1):

To solve your task using Timer you need to implement `TimerTask` with your code and use `Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate` method to run that code repeatedly:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.print("I would be called every 2 seconds");
    }
}, 0, 2000);
```

Also note that calling any UI operations must be done on Swing UI thread (or FX UI thread if you are using JavaFX):

```
   private int i = 0;
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(i++));
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 2000);
}
```

In case of JavaFX you need to update FX controls on "FX UI thread" instead of Swing one. To achieve that use `javafx.application.Platform#runLater` method instead of SwingUtilities

Comment: Thanks, but that's multithreading and I don't really know how to implement it within JavaFX GUI..

Comment: you can check this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801227/fast-counting-timer-in-javafx

Comment: You are changing the text of a JavaFX label from the AWT Event Dispatch thread. This violates JavaFX threading rules, and will likely throw an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: Even if it appears to work, it is subject to a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), which should be mitigated by surrounding the call to change text in [`Platform.runLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).

Answer (score -2):

```
    final Label clock = new Label();
    final DateFormat format = DateFormat.getInstance();
    final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    clock.setText(format.format(cal.getTime()));
                }
            }));

    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
```

Comment: Please note that "code only answers" are really discouraged. Just dumping code isn't very helpful for future readers. Focus on explaining what you are doing too!

Comment: why do you copy the other answer? the only reason might have been to modify it (to use the new Date/Time classes) which you didn't  ..