# JavaFX Live Time and Date

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am building currently an application using JavaFx with an extra feature that displays the current date and time in the top corner of the scene. Since I am new to JavaFX, I don't know how to implement this one.

I tried to use an old code in swing but I got an IllegalStateException Error.

Here's my code.

**MainMenuController.java**

```
@FXML private Label time;

private int minute;
private int hour;
private int second;

@FXML
public void initialize() {

    Thread clock = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            for (;;) {
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                //System.out.println(hour + ":" + (minute) + ":" + second);
                time.setText(hour + ":" + (minute) + ":" + second);

                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                     //...
                }
            }
        }
    };
    clock.start();
}
```

**MainMenu.fxml**

```
 <children>
   <Label fx:id="time" textFill="WHITE">
     <font>
       <Font name="Segoe UI Black" size="27.0" />
     </font>
   </Label>
   <Label fx:id="date" textFill="WHITE">
     <font>
       <Font name="Segoe UI Semibold" size="19.0" />
     </font>
   </Label>
 </children>
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
   }

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/MainMenu.fxml"));
       primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,1366, 768));
       primaryStage.show();
   }
}
```

As you notice, I tested it printing the live time in the console. Yeah it worked, but the label is still static.

Comment: Side note: if you're using Java SE 8 (or greater) it's recommended to use the new Date & Time API where possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [*JavaFX Displaying Time and Refresh in Every Second*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38566638/642706)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you need FX UI Thread `Platform.runLater(...)` for that, but you can do something like this using [`Timeline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) in you controller class,

```
@FXML
public void initialize() {

    Timeline clock = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e ->  
         time.setText(LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")))
    ),
         new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1))
    );
    clock.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    clock.play();
}
```

Alternative solution using [`AnimationTimer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) - suggested by @James_D,

```
AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {
        time.setText(LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
    }
};
timer.start();
```

The second approach using [`AnimationTimer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) seems much cleaner and more accurate than with [`Timeline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html).

---

<sup>You can check the POC of both approaches [`here`](https://github.com/shekharrai/stack-overflow-qa/blob/main/42383857-javafx-live-time-and-date-poc/src/main/java/com/stack/overflow/JavaFXLiveDateTime.java).</sup>

Comment: Note that a timeline updating every second has the potential to be anything up to a second behind the real time. Using an `AnimationTimer` will be as accurate as the UI rendering allows. It's probably also cleaner to use `LocalTime` and a `DateTimeFormatter` instead of the legacy `Calendar` class.

Comment: Would you have a solution for this error please? ```The constructor KeyFrame(Duration, (<no type> e) -> {}) is undefined```

Comment: @user_1330 which javafx version are you using? Since this issue is related to the javafx-8 +

Answer (score 10):

The @Shekhar Rai answer works well, but here is a shorter version who works pretty well too.

```
@FXML
Label dateTime;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    initClock();
}

private void initClock() {

    Timeline clock = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        dateTime.setText(LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter));
    }), new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1)));
    clock.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    clock.play();
}
```

The main advantage is that you dont have to define every variables  (seconds, minutes, ...)

Answer (score -3):

i have a simple method it may helps you

```
private JFXDatePicker txtDateVenteAV;
txtDateVenteAV.setValue(LocalDate.now());
```

Comment: no - the question is about updating the label, setting it once is unrelated